# Why it doesn't mask the complete layer?

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, pixel

Through the code I need to calculate the number of pixels of a layer composed by three classes (severe, medium and low), but the code just take into account the medium and low classes.

[image: LINE 41 AND 42 DON´T MASK COMPLETELY THE classified2 ayer]
https://code.earthengine.google.com/90af044b069216a2deb4a2d639b2fee7

Comment: Please add a minimal, working example of your code in textform to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var allpix =  classified2.updateMask(classified2)
```

This line will cause your pixels with class `0`, your `severe` class, to be masked. I'm not sure what your intention was here.

Comment: I want all the classes "severe", "medium" and "low" to be masked, but line 41 just masks "medium " and "low" classes.

Comment: What do you mean when you say _to be masked_? Please explain this more in detail. How do you want this to work? Which pixels should be masked out, which should stay?